# How to create a sized WKWebView in Swift 3 / iOS 10

Tags: swift, storyboard, ios10

I am attempting to add a WKWebView to my app that takes up about ~2/3 of the screen (leaving space at the bottom). Because there seems to be no way to add the `WKWebView` to the storyboard, I added a regular `UIView`. Then in my `viewDidAppear` method I try and create a `WKWebView` with the same bounds. Is this a sound approach?

My code looks like this:

```
    @IBOutlet var conversationView: UIView!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      let webView = WKWebView(frame: conversationView.frame)
      if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") {
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
      }

      // conversationView = webView // <-- doesn't work :\
      conversationView.addSubview(webView) // works!
    }
```

Swaping the views outright doesn't work at all, so instead I add the web view as a subview of the temporary view I added to the storyboard. This at least lets me constrain it's position and size but still it feels very kludgy and like there must be a better way of doing this..

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi, what does your UI look like now? can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @ChristianAbella screenshot added. The `conversationView` takes up most of the space, sitting below a label.

Comment: I have the same scenario in my project, but I just used self.view.addSubview(webView), instead of adding another UIView.

Answer (score 8):

None of the other answers worked for me. The answer by [Samip Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40857388/1852207) is along the right track but the constraints are not quite correct. The important thing to remember is to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false.

So, here's my solution. In the storyboard create a UIView with the constraints and layout you want for the WKWebView. In your view controller add the code:

```
@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
var wkWebView:WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    wkWebView = WKWebView(frame:contentView.frame)
    contentView.addSubview(wkWebView)
    constrainView(view: wkWebView, toView: contentView)

    let request = URLRequest(url: /* your url here */)
    wkWebView.load(request)
}
```

The code for constraining the view. You might add this to a utilities class if you want to use it more than one view controller.

```
func constrainView(view:UIView, toView contentView:UIView) {
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a very good approach; it is perfectly reasonable to have a "content view" whose job is merely to guide the web view into place, as it were. But it would be even better to add the web view *plus constraints* that size and position it.

Answer (score 1):

> If you want to give constraints that size and postion the webview with
>   respect to its container view, you can do like this.

```
     @IBOutlet weak var wkWebBackgroundView: UIView!
     var wkWebView:WKWebView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            setUpView()

        }
     func setUpView(){
            self.wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero)     
            self.wkWebBackgroundView.addSubview(wkWebView)

            let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: wkWebView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: wkWebBackgroundView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: wkWebView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: wkWebBackgroundView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: wkWebView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: wkWebBackgroundView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: wkWebView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: wkWebBackgroundView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

            view.addConstraints([leading, top, height, width])  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just size the webview frame as desired without using a different view.

```
let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height * 0.66).integral)
view.addSubview(webView)
```

However, if you need the view in the storyboard to line up other subview constraints then your method works fine.

Edit: Just saw your added screenshot with comment stating the view is below a label:

```
let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: label.frame.maxX + (whatever distance you want between label bottom and webView top), y: 0, 
width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height * 0.66).integral)
view.addSubview(webView)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this hope it works

Note: Please set Frame according to your requirements.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WKWebViewVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var wkWebviewBGView: UIView!
    var wkWebview: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

       super.viewDidLoad()

       wkWebview = WKWebView(frame: wkWebviewBGView.bounds, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
       wkWebview.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
       self.wkWebviewBGView.addSubview(wkWebview)

       let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
       wkWebview.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
   }
}
```